# How do I construct a NTM that accepts the language consisting of the coding of turing machines that halt on one input?

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism, semi-decidability

I currently have a problem with the following question:

Let $L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid \exists w: \text{$M$ halts for $w$ in at most $|w|^3$ steps} \}$.
Construct an NTM (non-deterministic Turing machine) that decides $L$.

My idea was to simulate every possible input of length $\le|w|^3$ on a given TM $M$ by using a separate band in my NTM for every single input word. If there is one band where $M$ halts, then the NTM accepts.

Is this the right way to go about it? My problem is that I don't see why I would need a NTM to decide $L$. A standard TM would be able to do the same thing.

Comment: "simulate every possible input"... Are you sure you can do this in *finite* time? For *every* possible input? Remember deciders need to halt to reject too!

Comment: Also, are you sure you mean "at least $|w|^3$ steps" and not "at *most* $|w|^3$ steps"?

Comment: sorry you are right, I meant at most |w|^3 steps. If it doesn't halt until then, I know that it is the wrong input.

Comment: maybe it helps to know that I use a NTM to show that L ist semi-decidable

Comment: Wait... Are you supposed to prove $L$ is decidable or *semi*-decidable? I do not think the former is correct...

Comment: Yep, L is semi-decidable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L$ is *semi*-decidable (or, synonymously, recursively enumerable). This can be proven (arguably) more easily by using an NTM which non-deterministically picks an input $w \in \{ 0, 1 \}^\ast$, simulates $M$ on it for at most $|w|^3$ steps, and accepts if and only if $M$ does. The NTM accepts exactly the language $L$ because, if there is no accepting branch of the NTM, then there is also no input $w$ for which $M$ halts in at most $|w|^3$ steps. For a properly written proof, it should also be said the semi-decidability of $L$ follows from the equivalence of DTM and NTM acceptors (remember (semi-)decidability is defined in terms of DTMs, *not* NTMs!).

Because of the equivalence of DTM and NTM acceptors, the above reasoning indirectly gives you a DTM which accepts $L$. The explicit construction could be picking an enumeration of inputs (e.g., lexicographical order), simulating $M$ on each input $w$ for at most $|w|^3$ steps, and accepting if and only if $M$ does. (Having to argue about the enumeration of inputs might be perceived as "hard" by some, hence why proving with an NTM could be considered "easier".)

A **warning**, however: $L$ is *not decidable*. This is because its complement is $\{ \langle M \rangle \mid \forall w: \text{$M$ does not halt for $w$ in at most $|w|^3$ steps} \}$ and, thus, a variant of the [complement of the halting problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74650/what-is-the-complement-of-halting-problem), which is notorious for not being semi-decidable.